# Writing Expect Script for random questions in while loop

Tags: expect

I am trying to write an expect script with a while loop where I have a set of questions that will be asked randomly again and again. I have created a script for the same but that is not working as expected. Is it important that all the expectations in the expect block should be in the sequence? Also, Is it the correct way of exiting the while loop in case of success?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f  
set timeout 1  
spawn ./AnotherFile.sh

while {1} {

        expect {
                {Enter password:}                                               {send -- "Password\r";exp_continue}
                {Trust this certificate? [no]:}                                 {send -- "yes\r";exp_continue}
                {Enter pass phrase:}                                            {send -- "Password\r";exp_continue}
                {Verifying - Enter pass phrase:}                                {send -- "Password\r";exp_continue}
                {Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:}                            {send -- "IN\r";exp_continue}
                {State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:}              {send -- "XX\r";exp_continue}
                {Locality Name (eg, city) []:}                                  {send -- "XXXXX\r";exp_continue}
                {Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:}   {send -- "XXXXX\r";exp_continue}
                {Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:}                    {send -- "XXXXX\r";exp_continue}
                {Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:}               {send -- "XXXXX\r";exp_continue}
                {Email Address []:}                                             {send -- "\r";exp_continue}
        }
        expect {
                {"Successfully Done."}                {send -- "exit\r"}
        }
}
expect eof  
close $spawn_id

You can also think of my problem in terms of "C" code as:

While(1)
{
    Switch(expect_command)
    {
        case "Enter Password": 
            send "Password\r"
        case "is certificate valid"
            send "yes\r"
        ...
        case "successfull"
            send "exit\r"
    }
}
```

Comment: No one knows how your `AnotherFile.sh` works. Please give a [repro].

Comment: You can also `expect -d /your/script.exp` and see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Put "Successfully Done" in the same `expect` command as the others. There should be at least one pattern that will not `exp_continue` so the `expect` command can actually end (without timing out).

Also, since you're in a `while 1` loop, you need to `send "exit\r"; break`